# preg_match regex required for specific UK postcode area code

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

My regex knowledge isn't the best and although I've been looking through posts to get my head around it I'm unable to find what I'm looking for.

I would like to use the following (where $postcode is the full postcode entered by the user):

```
if(preg_match("AREA CODE REGEX GOES HERE", $postcode))
{
    //Do something   
}
```

to do the following:

Check where postcode area code entered matches one of the following DN15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41 (all DN).

So I'm looking for the regex to match only those postcodes.  It could be DN21 1AB or DN21 2AB for example but it has to match the first part still of DN21.

I hope that's enough information and thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Looking through posts and searching Google is normally not as good as just checking [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php). You'll have to do it sooner or later ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this regex pattern, provided by the British Government itself:

```
(GIR 0AA)|((([A-Z-[QVX]][0-9][0-9]?)|(([A-Z-[QVX]][A-Z-[IJZ]][0-9][0-9]?)|(([A-Z-[QVX]][0-9][A-HJKSTUW])|([A-Z-[QVX]][A-Z-[IJZ]][0-9][ABEHMNPRVWXY])))) [0-9][A-Z-[CIKMOV]]{2})
```

So to apply it to your situation, you can first check that you're dealing with a valid UK post code, and then check if the first part starts with 'DN' and the second part is any one of the ranges in the accepted-numbers array:

```
$accepted_numbers = array_merge(range(15, 22), range(31, 41));

if (preg_match('#^(GIR ?0AA|[A-PR-UWYZ]([0-9]{1,2}|([A-HK-Y][0-9]([0-9ABEHMNPRV-Y])?)|[0-9][A-HJKPS-UW]) ?[0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2})$#', $postcode) && substr($postcode, 0, 2) == 'DN' && in_array(substr($postcode, 2, 2), $accepted_numbers)) {
       // The UK post code is valid according to your criteria
}
```

Source: http://webarchive.nationalarchives.gov.uk/+/http://www.cabinetoffice.gov.uk/media/254290/GDS%20Catalogue%20Vol%202.pdf (page 11)

Comment: A link would make this answer awesome.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and explanation!  Made it a lot clearer and exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Thanks @silkfire it works as charm! But I need this regex to accept lowercase letters too. Now it accepts only uppercase postcodes.

Comment: @vignesh Just add a case-insensitive flag to your regex. Now I do not know what language you're implementing this in but it's usually put after the delimiter and is `i`.

Comment: I found the link above didn't contain the Regex, but I found this government document that has a case-insensitive example on page 6 [Bulk data transfer](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/413338/Bulk_Data_Transfer_-_additional_validation_valid_from_March_2015.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

If you're only looking to match DN15-DN41 as I assume that's what "match only those postcodes" means, you can use:

```
if(preg_match("/^DN(1[5-9]|[23][0-9]|4[01])/", $postcode))
{
    //Do something   
}
```

Comment: That looks kind of awkward. I don't think Regular expressions are a good choice for number ranges. Perhaps extract the numbers after DN and do a logical *$nums >= 15 && $nums <= 41*.

Comment: I've yet to meet any regular expression that didn't look awkward.